# Attaching Kotlin sources to AAR doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, aar

I am trying to add Kotlin sources of an AAR in Android Studio 3.3.2. It doesn't work when I select "Choose Sources..." and choose the corresponding source.jar. Android Studio only displays "Attaching..." but nothing happens, as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Either there is a Bug in Android Studio since I can see a NoSuchElementException
 in the logs or the source.jar is not as needed. Any hint's to solve the issue are welcome.

Here is the exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleAttachSourcesProvider.getSourceFile(GradleAttachSourcesProvider.java:160)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleAttachSourcesProvider.access$100(GradleAttachSourcesProvider.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleAttachSourcesProvider$1$1.onSuccess(GradleAttachSourcesProvider.java:126)
```

NOTE: I opened a ticket for Android-Studio -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128352536

Comment: Are you trying to add AAR? If AAR is already added,make sure you have included it in gradle file as module dependency.

Comment: I am trying to add a sources.jar containing kotlin source files.

Comment: For that you need to configure kotlin with your project first.

Comment: It doesn'r work since the project is a pure java project, only the sources of the 3rd party lib are written in kotlin.

Comment: Even if your project is a pure java project, if you add a third party library using kotlin you need to have kotlin configured in your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure kotlin in your project following these steps:-

in `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
```

also add

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
```

Clean and Build your project. It worked for me.